# Is there a way to return to the command prompt temporarily

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, user-interaction

How would One allow users to "Pause the current Pipeline and return to the command prompt" and later resume in a powershell script?

I stumbled upon this line in a [blog post](https://jeffbrown.tech/how-to-create-prompts-in-powershell/) about User Interaction in Powershell

```
$suspend = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Suspend", "Pause the current pipeline and return to the command prompt. Type ""exit"" to resume the pipeline."
```

It was a mock option in a prompt imitating the appearance of a native command (Remove-Item). Lo and behold: That command actually Implements that behavior. Doing a quick Google Search, I did not find an implementation in a script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$Host.EnterNestedPrompt()` to suspend the current operation to enter a "nested" prompt - execution will resume once you exit it (using either `exit` or `$Host.ExitNestedPrompt()`):

```
function f {
  param([switch]$Intervene)

  $abc = 123

  if($Intervene.IsPresent){
    $host.EnterNestedPrompt()
  }

  Write-Host "`$abc has value '$abc'"
}
```

Now try invoking the function with and without the `-Intervene` switch:

[image]

Comment: Very cool stuff:)

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75298462/45375) is undoubtedly the best solution for your use case.

Because there is functional overlap, let me offer a solution for on-demand *debugging* of a script or function, using the [`Wait-Debugger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-debugger) cmdlet, which also enters a nested prompt in the current scope, while offering additional, debugging-specific functionality to step through the code.

```
function foo {
  'Entering foo.'
  if (0 -eq $host.ui.PromptForChoice('Debugging', 'Enter the debugger?', ('&Yes', '&No'), 1)) {
    Wait-Debugger
  }
  'Exiting foo.'
}
```

Executing `foo` presents a yes/no prompt for whether the debugger should be entered.

The debugging prompt can be exited with `exit` or simply `c` (one of the debugging-specific commands; `h` shows them all).